# html file input with accept="image/jpeg" also accepts heic on Android

Tags: android, html, file-upload

I have the following html input:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/jpeg">
```

When I use my (Android 11) phone to select a file, I can choose and upload .heic-Files aswell. On Windows, everything works as expected.

Has anyone a clue?

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: I use Chrome on my Android phone. And from Chrome, the default file browser of Android / or Samsung, not sure, launches to select the image.

Comment: Try different browsers and devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a specific image type from your `input` field you can do this :

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept=".jpeg, .jpg">
```